# Live Streaming and Broadcast Video Server

Tags: video, streaming, multimedia

I am trying to setup a live stream multimedia server something like Youtube live stream or https://twitch.tv that users can stream their webcam their desktop and so on.

I am searching a lot in the web but all are with payments some software I found like https://wowza.com are with payments.

Has anyone succeeded setting up a server like this?

Answer (score 1):

+1 on reading the docs for VLC as suggested in a comment in another answer.  I've successfully used vlc to generate streams from static files, video devices (capture card, webcam), or other streams that are then sent to another instance of VLC to be grabbed and broadcast, to a darwin streaming server (free/open version of quicktime streaming server), and to a wowza media server.

Be aware that all of those methods create a not-quiet-live broadcast - I've always gotten a 10-12 second delay, depending on which software was used.  Of course, the changes in software also incorporated faster processors, more RAM, better networks, etc so those may be the cause of the reduction in delay.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` for encoding, `vlc` for streaming. Both are open and free.

Comment: Yes I know this actually I was trying to find something more specific.
As I sent in the links they Web Streaming. VLC is a Software to watch the live Stream I can do this with Media Player as well to watch the strim. 
I need something specific to integrate all the Stuff some kind of guide or steps to take.
Thank you

Comment: I think, you may start with reading `vlc` documentation in order to find out what it really can.

Comment: +1 - vlc can do a lot more than watch a stream - it can generate a stream sent to a streaming server like darwin or wowza, it can host a stream directly, all sorts of stuff.